# Slack bot in Python that uses both RTM API and Interactive Messages

Tags: python, flask, slack-api

I'm building a Python app that uses [Slack's RTM API](https://api.slack.com/rtm). The app also needs to handle incoming HTTP requests from Slack in order to use the [Interactive Messages](https://api.slack.com/interactive-messages) feature. The application is a booking bot that responds to direct messages by offering days to book on after consulting another API.

It seems I need two asynchronous task, one to actively poll the RTM API and the second to handle incoming HTTP requests. I was going to use Flask to handle the HTTP requests, but since Flask is blocking by design, this is not going to work - I will not be able to run the second task at the same time.

I could always go for a async HTTP server, but it seems to me that what I'm trying to achieve must be a common use case and I would expect it to be easier to implement, so maybe I'm missing something here about the Slack API?

Comment: I would recommend to take a look at Slack's [Events API](https://api.slack.com/events-api). Its way easier to implement then RTM API since it does not require Websockets, has a similar functionality and you do not need to poll, since Slack will send you a request once an events happens